# TypeConverter usage for class property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a class `EntityItemValue` which has property named `Value` of type `object`, the actual type can be determined through property named `Type` which is residing inside `EntityItem` class.

```
public class EntityItemValue
{        
    public EntityItem Item { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    // other properties ...
}

public class EntityItem
{        
    public Type Type
    // other properties ...
}
```

Now I want to bind the `Value` property in Blazor component like this below.

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="input-style"><input type="text" @bind="@Param.Value" /></div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EntityItemValue Param { get; set; }
}
```

But getting this exception:

> The type 'System.Object' does not have an associated TypeConverter that supports conversion from a string. Apply 'TypeConverterAttribute' to the type to register a converter.'

I understand what is the issue here but how to use the `TypeConverter` correctly based on the `Type` property in class `EntityItem` any leads for implementation idea or a better proposal to tackle this problem?

Comment: Why not to use string instead of object? Or what is your intention after that?

Comment: @Alamakanambra, previously I was using string instead of object but holding different types in string representation was an issue, like DateTime can have different formats region wise and casting to DateTime was an issue. I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<input>` element is only binding to strings - we can first check this when the parameter is set:

```
protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    if (Param.Item.Type != typeof(string))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot bind a non string to a string input");
    }
}
```

Now that we have this, we can wrap the `object` as a `string`:

```
private string Value
{
    get => (string)Param.Value;
    set => Param.Value = value;
}
```

Finally update the input to bind to our string

```
<input type="text" @bind="@Value" />
```